# C++. Calling a virtual member function in destructor

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

Every class that gets extended with this calls abort in the destructor and the call stack tells me that the function that called abort was called from a unreasonable spot in the header file. The other functions get overriden and work fine though.

Renderable.h

```
#pragma once
class Renderable
{
public:
    virtual void update(long delta) = 0;
    virtual void destroy() = 0;
    virtual void render() = 0;
    virtual ~Renderable();
};
```

Renderable.cpp

```
#include "Renderable.h"

Renderable::~Renderable()
{
    (this->*(&Renderable::destroy))(); // GLUtils::runOnUIThreadWithContext(this, &Renderable::destroy, true);
} // It says that it gets called from here.
```

[image: Calls abort.]
[image]

Comment: Why don't you `press retry to debug the application`? And why don't you just call `destroy()`?

Comment: whattttt arrreee youuuu doinnnggggggg

Comment: You know `(this->*(&Renderable::destroy))();` is just an absurdly complicated way of writing `destroy();` right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When instantiating an object the base class gets initialized and then the subclass gets initialized.  When destructing an object the subclass gets destructed and then the base class.  After the subclass is destructed, its members and virtual methods are unavailable—there is no `destroy()` method to be invoked.  I suggest you move the logic in the `destroy()` method to the subclass destructor.